# JavaScript/HTML component for '2D' scroll bar / 2D vector control

Tags: javascript, html, gui

I have a web interface with a number of controls for 'tweaking' variables in another running program. Mostly the variables are scalar, and tweaking can be done using a linear 'slider' control, or scroll bar, such as this one:

http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/

I also have some 2D vectors I would like a control for - I'm imagining a box with a handle in it, where the handle can be dragged on both axes, which updates two variables, one for each axis.

I'm not totally sure what I would name such a component though ("2D scroll bar" doesn't make much sense!), so I'm finding it hard to search for existing software that implements it, if such a thing exists. Can anyone suggest either software that does this, or a better name for it?

Solution needs to be open source. I don't care about browser compatibility - only up-to-date Chrome needs to be supported. Bonus points if the solution integrates nicely with AngularJS 1.2, and mega bonus points if the control works nicely with mobile touch-screen devices.